# From SVN to GIT and back again

Tags: git, svn

We are working on a project where we are required to use Subversion as our version control system. We are all comfortable with it, but, on the holidays we would like to go out of town to focus on development. The problem is, there is a high probability not to have internet access where we're going. Since we still want to maintain code history, I was thinking if there was a way to export our current Subversion history to a git repository and then export our git history to the existing Subversion repo (this repo already has history on it).

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You focus on development *on holidays*? Shouldn't you focus on things unrelated to work? :)

Comment: Haha yeah, but it is kind of a school project, so during school we don't have time to code =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of tutorials about this. Check:

- [Howto use Git and svn together](http://flavio.castelli.name/howto_use_git_with_svn)
- [git-svn](http://www.digikam.org/?q=node/270)

Answer (score 7):

First Rule of Git: if you can think of it, Git can do it. Have a look at [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take your repository with you, then why not locally host the repository (or a copy) on one of your computers you take with you (assuming you are going together) - then you only need to have a local network.

But maybe I misunderstood your question's objectives.

Comment: We could, but we don't host the repo ourselves. It's hosted by our University which I don't think is going to give us access to the full repo.